# Custom initializer "initWithImage" not showing image in view

Tags: ios, ios6

I have written the following custom initializer in my `Missiles.m` file (`Missile.h` inherits from `UIView`):

```
-(id)initWithMissileImage: (UIImage *)image
{
    CGRect missileFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    self = [super initWithFrame:missileFrame];

    if (self) {
        _missileImage = image; //these are declared as strong properties
        _deltaX = 0;
        _deltaY = -1;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and in my `ViewController.m`, I call the initializer as such:

```
-(void)fireMissileWithDeltaX: (float)x andY: (float)y
{
    Missiles *missile = [[Missiles alloc] initWithMissileImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"missile.png"]];
    //other code here...
    [self.view addSubview:missile];
}
```

However, the .png image of the missile fails to display.  I have alternatively tried using just a drawn square box just to test if the code works, and it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where do you use `_missileImage` after initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you have posted, you have not drawn the image in any way.  Put this in your custom initializer after you set the properties.

```
UIImageView *missileView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_missileImage];
[self addSubview:missileView];
```

Alternatively, if you use `_missileImage` elsewhere in an attempt to display it, please post that code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't do anything with the image other than keep a reference. You have two options:

1) Update your `Missile` class to add a `UIImageView` to itself and show the image there.

or

2) Implement the `drawRect:` method in your `Missile` class and draw the image there.

Option 1 is probably easier.